# Why does the Twitter tag exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

One of the questions that recently popped up on the homepage had only one tag - [twitter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)

According to the [Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), only the following topics are allowed:

> WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and
>   administrators to ask questions about:
>
> - theme and plugin development
> - development and management best practices
> - server configuration for WordPress

[twitter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) (the social network) does not fit in any of these categories, so why does it even exist?

---

It also seems there are various questions using that tag that are not to do with WordPress and have not been flagged. A good example is [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/214241/84836)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of tags that are off-topic tags most of which are plugin specific: *almost* anything [[plugin-*]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development+or+plugin-recommendation+or+plugin-w3-total-cache+or+plugin-contact-form-7+or+plugin-jetpack+or+plugin-gravity-forms+or+plugin-wpml+or+plugin-wp-seo-yoast+or+plugin-wp-e-commerce+or+plugin-nextgen-gallery+or+plugin-json-api+or+plugin-qtranslate+or+plugin-list-category-post+or+plugin-tinymce+or+plugin-wp-pagenavi+or+plugin-wp-supercache+or+plugin-custom-permalinks+or+plugin-posts-to-posts+or+plugin-redirection+or+plugin-polylang) and [woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) etc. Since Stack Exchange is a community based platform the community decides what tags may be relevant to their question - and any user [greater than 300 rep](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) can just create any tag they see fit.

This doesn't mean questions regarding the tag are either on-topic or off-topic - that's also for the community to decide. Most Javascript questions would be considered off-topic but there are cases where the javascript is specifically pertaining to WordPress like involving the customizer, media library, admin-ajax, etc.

For the most part it's a nice way to group off-topic questions and for you to exclude questions with this tag in your WPSE Settings.